# Angular 2 subscribe doesnt work

Tags: angular

i m getting exception 'Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined'but i dont get it what am i doing wrong.

```
checkUserCredentials() {
    let response;
    let user = {email: this.email, password: this.password};
    this.userService.getUser(user).subscribe((res) => response = res);
  }
```

Service :

```
getUser(user): any {
    //this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?email = '+user.email+'&password='+user.password,
    let headers = new Headers();
    let postResponse;
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        {headers:headers})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return within the `getUser` method:

```
getUser(user): any {
  let headers = new Headers();
  let postResponse;
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users',
    JSON.stringify(user),
    {headers:headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}
```

Comment: but i get from console.log(response) in the method checkUserCredentials().. any idea why ?

Comment: You try to subscribe on the observable returned by your http request... Don't forget that such call is asynchronous and you provide a callback (here an arrow function) when subscribing.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `return` missing. The method doesn't return anything, therefor it implicitly returns `undefined` which results in the error you get:

```
getUser(user): any {
    //this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users?email = '+user.email+'&password='+user.password,
    let headers = new Headers();
    let postResponse;
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    // vvv missing return
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users',
        JSON.stringify(user),
        {headers:headers})
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
```